# How to set lower triangular matrix of 0-1?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

I need to make a matrix, for n dimensions, to look like this for n=4:

```
[0,0,0,0]
[1,0,0,0]
[1,1,0,0]
[1,1,1,0]
```

because I need the positions of the 1s, ie

```
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
1, 2
1, 3
2, 3
```

This is because I want to work out the distances between x points, without wasting time repeating a distance. These coordinates will let me do it only once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You essentially want to increment the number of `1`s (starting from 0) in each row, while padding the rest of the row with `0`s, thereby keeping a constant length. Try something like this:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> [[1]*i + [0]*(n - i) for i in xrange(n)]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

---

If you're using NumPy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.tril(np.ones((n, n), dtype=int), -1)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions to the rescue!

`>>> matrix = [[1]*i + [0]*(4-1) for i in range(4)]`

Substitute 4 with any range you want. For Python lower than 3.X you should you `xrange` instead of `range`

Answer (score 1):

for `n=5`

```
matrix = [[1 if x<y else 0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
```

The output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Instead of `1 if x<y else 0` you can also simply use `int(x<y)`, just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

You explained that your reason for wanting the lower triangular matrix is to get the positions of the 1s.  If that is really the only reason for making the matrix, there are more efficient ways to generate those positions.  In particular, `itertools.combinations(range(n), 2)` would work:

```
In [209]: import itertools

In [210]: list(itertools.combinations(range(4), 2))
Out[210]: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```